# Does 私は地震が怖い make sense?

Tags: grammar, translation, particle-は, particle-が

> 私は地震が怖い。

For me that's like saying 私は彼がきれいです.
It doesn't make sense putting 私 here.

Comment: 私は彼が(は)きれいだと思う makes sense.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> 私は地震**が怖い**。*lit.* As for me, earthquakes are scary. → I *am scared of* earthquakes.

Your sentence is correct and natural.

が is used with several adjectives that indicate one's feelings, e.g. 「怖い」「欲しい」「つらい」「楽しい」「恐ろしい」「悲しい」「うれしい」「うらやましい」「憎い」「愛しい」 (i-adjectives) 「好きだ」 「嫌いだ」「いやだ」「心配だ」「面倒だ」「楽しみだ」 (na-adjectives) etc.

Examples:

> 「僕は自転車**が欲しい**。」 I *want* a bicycle.
>   「私は日本語の勉強**が楽しい**。」 I *enjoy* learning Japanese.
>   「山田さんはコーヒー**が好き**だ。」 Yamada-san *likes* coffee.

<sub>が is also used with the desiderative auxiliary 「～たい」. eg 「私はコーヒー**が**飲み**たい**。」 I *want to* drink coffee.</sub>

Answer (score 1):

While it may be *redundant*, using `私は` certainly does make sense here and may even be necessary in some contexts to avoid ambiguity. A somewhat contrived example:

```
彼は幽霊{ゆうれい}屋敷{やしき}は苦手{にがて}、私は地震が怖い。 
He doesn't like haunted houses, and I'm afraid of earthquakes.
```

Your second example is indeed somewhat nonsensical but is not equivalent to the first.

Answer (score 1):

私は地震が怖い makes sense and the user "Chocolate" has given a very good explanation.

Other ways to express the fear of earthquakes could be:

地震が怖いんだよ。I'm telling you, earthquakes are scary.

地震は私の一番恐怖です。Earthquakes are my biggest fear.

地震はとても恐ろしいと思います。I think earthquakes are very scary.

地震の時パニクりた。I panicked at the time of the earthquake.