# やさしさがうれしい meaning

Tags: meaning

I came across this phrase example in my grammar book, but I don't know if I fully understand the meaning.

> 留学したとき、クラスの友達のやさしさがとてもうれしかった。

Can やさしさ be described as うれしい?
And what does that exactly mean?

Comment: Related: https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56736/9831

Answer (score 2):

やさしさがうれしい means "to be glad about kindness". That is "She(He) was glad about her(his) classmates' kindness".

Comment: I understand the meaning but can が be used in that way too? Because it is the first time I see it

Comment: Yes, it can. You can think that like 私は is omitted. It is 私は、クラスの友達のやさしさがとてもうれしかった. 私は is the subject, うれしかった is the  predicate,  クラスの友達のやさしさ is the object. Generally, a object marker is を, but when predicate is an adjective, it become が. For example, 私は、彼の結婚が悲しかった.