# Why in the sentence below は particle is used instead of の?

Tags: particle-は

> アンアさん**は**声がきれいです。

And not

> アンアさん**の**声がきれいです。

Comment: This [answer](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/a/56736/5176) should be useful.

Comment: Related: [Double Subject Constructions](https://www.japanesewithanime.com/2019/08/double-subject-constructions.html)

Comment: I agree, the answer that @Will links to (and the other answers to the same question) explain most of the difference.

Comment: The answer I linked to arguably has a slightly different/narrower scope though. (Surprisingly, I could not find a perfect Q&A duplicate.) @naruto's (external) link seems like a better reference.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Does 私は地震が怖い make sense?](https://japanese.stackexchange.com/questions/56730/does-%e7%a7%81%e3%81%af%e5%9c%b0%e9%9c%87%e3%81%8c%e6%80%96%e3%81%84-make-sense)